# Count Data using multiple critea 1 formula excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have table excel like this

[image]

i want to know, how to count data parameter Nationality **Singaporean** and Gender "**Male**"

i'm try formula like this => **=COUNTIFS(A2:C6,{"Male","Singaporean"})**
this result 3 it's wrong result because result it's 2

Help me thank's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untested but

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B6,"Singaporean", C2:C6, "Male")
```

should work